# How to find a set of values for the input features to maximize the output value in an already trained node artificial neural network

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

Suppose I have an already trained artificial neural network that uses a set of features to predict a probability. Each training example represents an individual person. Some of the features are fixed characteristics of a person (e.g. race, gender, ...), while the other features are things that can change (for example, diet, medication, ...) and they are all binomial (either 0 or 1). Now, if I have a new person (not from the training set), and we already know the values for the fixed characteristics for him/her, while the values for other features are unknown. How can I find the optimal values for the unknown features that yield the maximum output probability, given the fixed values? Thanks!